# Clear params if condition is met Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I can't figure this out and it doesn't seem to be directly discussed anywhere that I can find. This is my question: how do I reset params so that the params hash is empty I render 'new'?

```
    a = ['United', '1769']

    Airline.all.each do |z| 
      if z.carrier == a[0] && z.flight == a[1]
        #DO SOME STUFF
      elsif z.carrier != a[0] || z.flight != a[1]
        #CLEAR PARAMS HERE/DELETE CURRENT INSTANCE
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

I want to iterate through Airline and compare against an array 'a' of previously stored user input to ensure they match. If one or both of the objects in the array does not match anything in Airline I essentially want to tell the user "Hey, that doesn't exist, we're gonna start you over." Rendering 'new' sends it to the new controller action just fine, but it preserves the params previously set for the object in question.

So how do I say "if one or both things in Airline don't match user input, clear the params hash and THEN send it to the 'new' action in the controller"? Ideally I would like to do this without telling it to destroy the current object instance (or the last - which seems to effectively be the same thing), because that works, but is resulting in a frozen hash when I render 'new'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the params hash you should redirect the user to a page where he could start over.

Replace this line `render 'new'` with something like this:

```
redirect_to new_airlines_path, alert: 'Please start over...'
```

Comment: Yes, ideally I do not want to manipulate the params hash...I've heard that's a big no-no and can cause all sorts of issues.Your suggestion brought up another error (that I think I can work around - it's in a loop, so it's calling for redirect many times. Have to break that loop while still iterating through all of Airline), so I think it will work. But I don't quite understand why it works...is it convention that params are reset upon redirects?

Comment: Yes, a redirect reloads the page and therefore resets the params (You get a new set of params with each request).